# Why do we use Matrix and canvas in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in Android, I need your help for understanding what this code is actually doing. As I am unable to get its purpose, and I am unable to get why we are using matrix and canvas in this:

**My Java Code**

```
float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float mieX));
    Log.d("middleY",String.valueOf(middleY));
    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);
           Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
```

Comment: you should go through some tutorial instead of asking what this code does.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas == View
All Views in Android uses Canvas/ViewPort to draw it's visible content. The Matrix is in simplicity the current drawing board for the Canvas.